# How to re-select selected cells in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

Let's say I've selected a few cells in the sheet:

[image]

In particular: **A3, C3, B5, D6, C7, E8, A9, C9, E9**

But then I've accidentally clicked away to a different cell (i.e. **E1**) and the whole selection is lost.

Is there a way to restore cells selection with a shortcut to the state how it was before I clicked **E1**? CTRL+Z doesn't work for this, it restores back value input.

Comment: It's called a named range

Comment: As far as I know you do not have an Undo for this... But try to search for it under the menu. Good luck and let me know.

Comment: No, there is no way to re-select cells which is lost. But if you only want to select cells with content, you can use GO TO option in Excel.

Answer (score 0):

*As per my knowledge, no Excel Function or Keyboard  Shortcut could reselect those selected cells, therefore I would like to suggest a method will help you to highlight cells been selected, and then how to reverse it.*

*You could use the shown method as a best alternative of the command `Ctrl+Mouse Click`, to avoid the accidental loss.*

1. Press **ALT+F11** to open VB editor.
2. **Copy & Paste** below shown code as 
   **Standard Module**.

**Macro 1: Highlight Double Clicked Cell.**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    Cancel = True
    Target.Interior.ColorIndex = IIf(Target.Interior.ColorIndex >= 15, -4142, 15)
End Sub
```

**Macro 2: Reverse the Highlighted Cell.**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeRightClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    Cancel = True
    Target.Interior.ColorIndex = IIf(Target.Interior.ColorIndex >= 0, -4142, 0)
End Sub
```

**Note,** 1st Macro will Highlight each cell been **Double clicked**, and 2nd will reverse the action on **Right Click**.